# Pagination - Symfony

Tags: symfony1, propel

I have the following code:

```
public function executeList()
{
    $c = new Criteria();
    $c->setLimit(5);
    $this->latest = ItemPeer::doSelectLatest($c);
}
```

Now I'd like to be able to use pagination with this, using sfPropelPager.

How could I use that with the code above, making sure It paginates results from the peer method?

Comment: @user390426: It's great that you found the answer yourself, but to stay in the format of the site it's better if you post is as an answer too. You can accept that, if you want.

Comment: Actually it's my reply pasted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working:

Code is as follows:

```
$pager = new sfPropelPager('Item', 10);
$pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
$pager->setPeerMethod('doSelectLatest');
$pager->init();
$this->pager = $pager;
```

Comment: It's a copy of my answer without setting counter method.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to set limit explicitly. sfPropelPager will do it for you.

Example:

```
$pager = new sfPropelPager(’Item’, 5);
$pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
$pager->setPeerMethod('doSelectLatest');
$pager->setPeerCountMethod('doCountLatest');
$pager->init();
```

[sfPropelPager reference](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfPropelPager)